# How to make Eclipse generate OSGi Declarative Services Bundle Component XML automatically with bnd annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, bnd

We do NOT want to use Bndtools at the moment due to the fact that we use Multi Modular Maven Projects.

At the moment we would like to add or modify bnd annotations and have Eclipse generate the component.xml files in an OSGI-INF folder automatically, just like Maven generates the Manifest automatically.

Right now each time we change the annotations, we must perform a Maven Package on each bundle, extract the new OSGI-INF folder from the jar and add it to the bundle, manually. This is tiresome, confusing, error prone and time consuming!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself

Answer (score 1):

There is an Eclipse plug-in to process DS annotations with PDE: [Declarative Services Annotations Support](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/declarative-services-annotations-support)

Answer (score 0):

The maven bundle plugin supports creating the DS component.xml files. Just add

```
 <Service-Component>*</Service-Component>
```

to the configuration instructions.

See: https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/db/command2/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does create the DS component.xml however we need to build the jar to be able to extract this file. We need a way to add annotations and have eclipse generate the xml file in real time, if this is possible.

Comment: I dont think it is possible. The question is why do you need this?

Comment: We are using pde and this means that the OSGI-INF folder needs to be in the root of the Eclipse project. We would like to add bnd annotations and simply run the project inside eclipse without having to build each bundle individually.

Comment: You could try the unpackBundle option of the bundle:manifest goal. See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-2.3.7/doc/site/manifest-mojo.html